# What is difference between bless and tie in perl?

Tags: perl, tie, bless

I was practicing some interview questions where I found this. I had a look at `perldoc -f tie` but couldn't get it. I know about `bless` and is using in my programs.
 
Can anyone tell me what is `tie` and how it is related and different from `bless`, and its usage? I will appreciate any simple example.
PS: I am a perl developer and using it in day to day life. My concern is not for interview, but for knowing it

Comment: I don't think I would want to work in a place that asks this kind of interview question.

Comment: I am a perl developer and using it in day to day life. So my concern is not for interview, but for knowing it.

Comment: DId you read http://perldoc.perl.org/perltie.html as well?

Comment: fortunately I was just reading the same doc and this link too `http://www.perlmonks.org/bare/?node_id=461198`

Comment: That's not very detailed about `tie`. Some example uses of `tie` are to use an array for a file, where each row represents a line in a file, and if you change array elements, stuff magically happens on disk, or tying a hash to some function so you can call `$tied_hash{$arg}` and it will call a function with `$arg` under the hood. But I've never built anything with `tie` myself.

Comment: Here is an abstract similarity.  A `tie` associates (or, equips) a variable with some behavior, action. So when you just read a tied scalar, things happen -- anything you code.  Perhaps a database entry is made, or a text message sent.  The `bless` associates a variable (reference) with a package.  So now when you use that reference (an object) anything you coded may happen.  So both associate a variable with actions.

Comment: `bless` allows you to calls methods on the blessed object.  
`tie` allows you to override built-in operations on variables, namely reading from/assigning to scalars, and list and hash operations like indexing, exists, delete etc.
So in some sense, `tie` works on a variable and `bless` works on a thing that is stored in a variable.

Comment: tie is an interesting one - it lets you do all sorts of clever things, but I'm not honestly sure it's good style to make a 'standard' variable do funky things like that, because it's action at a distance. Future programmers might expect `$funky_tied_var` to behave in a way that it doesn't.  But for testing, it can be really pretty handy to have 'magic' going on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`bless` is used to construct an object.

`tie` allows code to provide a variable for interface. e.g. It might look like you are assigning to a variable, but you are really calling a sub. `tie` and other forms of magic are primarily used to provide "clever" interfaces (e.g. altering `%ENV` alters the environment, altering `%SIG` sets signal handlers, `$!` mirrors both `errno` and `perror`, etc). It can also be used to extend the usefulness of existing code (e.g. creating something that looks like a file handle allows one to reuse code that expects to get its input from a file handle).

Answer (score 3):

I would probably answer your interview question like this:

Tie and bless serve similar functions, in that they associate custom behaviour with a variable. The difference comes in terms of focus - `tie` is about adding new behaviour to a 'standard' data structure, where `bless` is about creating a 'new' data structure altogether.

You are therefore more limited with `tie` to the fundamental operations of the data type you're working with, where a `bless`ed data structure has an almost unlimited scope of possiblity. But the tradeoff is that `tie`ed variables can serve as drop in replacements - if you extend a 'hash' by `tie`ing it to a file or a database, it can still function in the same way without any sort of code revision needed.

This strength is also in many ways it's weakness though - where a future programmer when confronted with an object and a method call in some code, would know they need to look to the class to understand what's going on - they might not realise that a tied hash (or scalar) is doing 'something special'.

I would therefore suggest that as a matter of style `tie` should be reserved for a diagnostic and testing role - it may be handy to log when a value changes in a hash, but shouldn't be used to make things behave in unexpected ways.